# Which predator raises its tail to signal no threat?

Tags: zoology, ethology

A guy in a bar once told me that there is some animal which raises its tail when at a watering area in order to signal to the other animals that it's not going to attack. He told me this as an argument to justify humans eating other animals.

Is this true that some animals do this? If so which ones? Links to video evidence would be extra appreciated.

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: Hmm.. it could just be me, but that sounds slightly unusual -- that a predator would be inclined to tell other animals "don't worry, I won't attack you". There could however be a stance of the predator that prey interpret to be the most relaxed, comfortable position of the predator, and therefore is least likely to attack while in that position (a position where the tail would be oriented upwards). Anyone agree? Disagree?